# How can I assign a command to a key?

Tags: shortcut-keys, apple, power-management

I want to assign a special command to be executed when I press the `F15` keyboard on a MAC keyboard under Ubuntu. This is the key on top of the `PgUp` key on the aluminium keyboard for Macs. I use that keyboard with Linux and I love it. In this case, I would like the `F15` key to suspend the PC. The command for this is:

```
pmi action suspend
```

Answer (score 4):

Goto `Keyboard`

Select `Shorcuts` > `Custom shortcuts`

Select the Plus button

Name your shortcut and type the command and apply

It will appear in the custom shortcut section click on the item on top of the disabled text
Then it will change to New shortcut Press F15 You will get the new shortcut :)